# How to measure the stability of hyperparameter selection in a model-building procedure?

Tags: machine-learning, model-selection, hyperparameter-tuning

For my project I run several model-building-procedures. I use the mean and standard deviation of the test scores in the outer folds as an estimator for the generalizability of the model-building procedure. However I wonder if there is also a way to estimate the stability of the selected values for my hyperparameters? Something like a distance-measurement?

**Example 1:**

As an example, let's say I ran a nested cross validation with a Support Vector Machine as Classifier. I implemented *C* and *Kernel* as hyperparameters. Note that *C* is a continous variable whereas *Kernel* is a categorial variable. I also smoothed my data and implemented the *Smoothing FWHM* as hyperparameter. I get the following values for my hyperparameters over the outer folds:

[image: 'Unstable Hyperparameter Selection']

You can see that each surrogate-model contains slightly different values for my hyperparameters.

**Example 2:**

In the second example you can see that each of my surrogate models won with the same selected values or categories for my hyperparameters. Thus this model-buidling-procedure could be called more stable with regards to hyperparameter value selection.

[image]